# Using the 'wallpaper' package to put a background on all but one page

Tags: backgrounds

I'm placing a background in my report document, using the LaTeX [wallpaper](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper) package. However, I am not able to easily place a document on all pages except for one (the title page). I am using `\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{background.pdf}` in my preamble to set the background, but if I use `\ClearWallPaper`, which was the only related command I found in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/wallpapermanual.pdf), then the background simply disappears on all pages.

How can I make the background appear in the whole document, except for on a specific page (without having to add it manually to all pages)?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{background.pdf}` in the document itself, not in the preamble:

Putting it on a specific page (e.g. after `\newpage` or `\end{titlepage}` or whatever) will make the background appear on all pages *starting from that page*.

(Similarly, putting `\ClearWallPaper` on some page will remove the background from all pages starting with that one.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the *xwatermark* package. You can specify the pages that should receive the watermark. Use the key

```
pages={2-\lastdocpage}
```