# Problem with wallpaper package

Tags: backgrounds, wallpaper

I want to show one every page a file as background except the page one, there should be another background.
I'm trying to do this with the code below. The problem is, that on the first page the pdf-files are one upon the other and you can see both.

Is there a solution, that the first page just show the first file as background ?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

% Background for the first and the following sides
\newcommand{\setBackground}[2]{
    \IfFileExists{#1}{\ThisTileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{#1}}

    \IfFileExists{#2}{\TileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{#2}}
}

\begin {document}
\setBackground{file1.pdf}{file2.pdf}
\lipsum
\pagebreak
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47685/using-the-wallpaper-package-to-put-a-background-on-all-but-one-page?rq=1    and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image

Comment: Use the eso-pic package. There is a command `\AddtoShipoutPictureBG*`, which makes displays the picture only on this page. On the next page use the same command without a star.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The problem is, that i cannot catch the pagebreak, because there is sometimes a very large table in the document over 2 or 3 pages. So i have to set the backgrounds at the beginning in the document or i catch in other way the pagebreak.